# Coordinate sync b/w image(cursor) and webcam(Open-CV)captured co-ordinate

Tags: python, opencv, user-interface, image-processing, computer-vision

I have been doing the pupil detection(gaze-tracking), and the opencv id throwing the x,y co-ordinates in the webcam space, the co-ordinates bring of the red marker in an image, i.e. the red marker’s co-ordinates is being `(1096,677)`. Now, I am checking the co-ordinates of the same red marker through mathplotlib `plt.imshow`, it’s showing `(36,46)`. So, my question is how shall I synchronize both of them, so that the gaze tracking will show the correct screen based co-ordinates. Is this related to screen-resolution(I checked with the python code

```
from AppKit import NSScreen
print(NSScreen.mainScreen().frame())
NSScreen.mainScreen().frame().size.width
NSScreen.mainScreen().frame().size.height
```

which is `(1496,976)`, I am trying to match the frame resolution by **cv2.resize** after cv2.vidroCapture(), I mean still the tracker is wrong. Can anyone help?

Comment: you wanna do a GUI? use a GUI toolkit. do not use OpenCV. it's for computer vision, not for GUIs.

Comment: I mean, it’s not that, the video(OPENCV) should be matching with the cursor co-ordinates. I was referring to this link, I mean how to put this python wise into the gaze coordinates?https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/CVonline/LOCAL_COPIES/OWENS/LECT9/node2.html